# Not able to trace all http requests in async parallel with zipkins in Node API

Tags: node.js, zipkin

I am new to node js and was trying to integrate zipkins with my node APi using appmetrics-zipkin npm package. Zipkin works fine except when there are multiple http calls in async  parallel method , it gives trace of only the first http call which was finished...I need trace for all the API calls in async parallel......Please help

Answer (score 0):

Well, without seeing any code, I could only give you a sample of how you should achieve this. So an http call, for example if you use node-fetch or axios will return a promise. To wait for promises paralelly, you can do the following:

```
async function myParallelRequests() {
    const requestOne = fetch(urlOne);
    const requestTwo = fetch(urlTwo);
    const requestThree = fetch(urlThree);
    const [responseOne, responseTwo, responseThree] = await Promise.all([
        requestOne,
        requestTwo,
        requestThree,
    ]);
}
```

Note that I use fetch API here, provided in node by the node-fetch package. Fetch returns a `Promise`. Then I call `Promise.all(promises)` where `promises` is a `Promise` array. You can then do whatever you would like to do with the 3 responses and your requests were made paralelly.

Hope this helps, good luck!